# How to activate (imap) php extension on IIS 6 with FastCGI?

Tags: php, iis, imap, fastcgi

I am using a Windows 2003 Server along with PHP 5. PHP is connected with IIS by FastCGI.

I need to activate the imap extension in PHP, so I edited the php.ini:

- I checked the extension path, it's OK.
- I uncommented the line "extension=php_imap.dll" by deleting the leading ";".
- I restarted the server.

But nothing happens, the imap extension stays inactive.
What am I missing here?